# How it is possible to operate on 47GB data frame?

Tags: r

I thought R is loadin everything to RAM. How it is possible to get data.frame which weights more than 47GB ? :O

I am also able to use it with functions. How?!

This is how I have made this data.frame:

```
set.seed(200) 
n <- 10000000
dt <- data.frame(default = as.logical(sample(x=c(F,T), size=n, replace=T,
                                             prob=c(.9,.1))),
                 f_prawna = as.factor(sample(x=c("SA","Sp. z o.o","OF",
                                                     "ROL", "inne",NA, 
                                                     "cywilna","kom",
                                                     "kom-akc","spol", "panst"
                 ), size=n, replace=T)),
                 branza = as.factor(sample(x=c("transp","bud","wolny","pref",
                                               "inny"), size=n, replace=T)),
                 asset = as.factor(sample(x=c("osd","miu","miu2","miu3",
                                              "truck"), size=n, replace=T)),
                 czy_uwaga = as.factor(sample(x=0:1, size=n, replace=T))

)

for (i in 1:8){
  dt <- cbind(dt,dt)
}

dim(dt)
```

A prove: [image: a picture]

Comment: (1) How much RAM does your machine have? (2) Are you sure it’s actually a `data.frame` and not something else? What `class` does your object have?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  Check the [HPC task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) section on "large memory and out-of-memory data"

Comment: RAM is cheap. It's not impossible to have access to a computer with sufficient RAM. And you can always use an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: I have 8 GB RAM. I'm sure it is a data.frame.

Comment: @wBacz Then, by principle of exclusion, the data.frame isn’t actually 47 GB large. Where did you get this number from?

Comment: I'm pasting a code above how I have created this data.frame. And the number of 47GB I got from RStudio.

Comment: what does `object.size(dt) / 1073741824` give

Comment: what does R Studia says? (look upward)

Comment: @wBacz RStudio is probably simply wrong here. They use heuristics, and it fails occasionally. Your data.frame has identical columns (from `cbind`) sharing data, rather than having copies. Try modifying a single value in each column, this will blow up your memory.

Comment: @KonradRudolph is correct. `object.size()`, which RStudio presumably uses, doesn't account for shared elements. If you run `pryr::object_size(dt)`, you'll get the true value of 200 MB for this object. For a discussion on shared elements and memory utilization, see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html.